# Не вешается disable на option в классе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Стоит задача поставить disable в тег option если значения продукта меняется.

```
jQuery('.services_products').on('change','.product',function(value){

    if ( $(this).val() == 1 ) {
        console.log('Скрываем не нужные блоки к продукту');
        $(".js_table").css("display", "block");
        $(".js_computer").css("display", "block");
    }

    if ( $(this).val() == 2 ) {
        console.log('К примеру Рыба');
        $(".js_table").css("display", "none");
        $(".js_computer").css("display", "none");
        $(".js_country").css("display", "block");

        $(".js_country option[value='6']")
            .attr("disabled", "disabled")
            .siblings().removeAttr("disabled");

        $("option[value='7']")
            .attr("disabled", "disabled")
            .siblings().removeAttr("disabled");
    }

});
```

Почему не работает .js_country option[value='6']? В то время как $("option[value='7']") работает, а значит и jQ тоже.

```
<div class="row js_country">
<label for="country">Страна происхождения</label>
<select class="service_custom_select" id="country" name="fuel" aria-invalid="false">
<option name="country_id" value="1">Страна</option>
<option name="country_id" value="2">Страна</option>
<option name="country_id" value="3">Страна</option>
<option name="country_id" value="4">Страна</option>
<option name="country_id" value="5">Страна</option>
<option name="country_id" value="6">Страна не отключена</option>
<option name="country_id" value="7">Страна отключена </option>
<option name="country_id" value="8">Страна</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: потому что `option` относится к селекту, а не к диву?

Comment: потому что следующая за ним операция с option[value='7'] по сути отменяет действие предыдущей. Селектор должен работать

Comment: По-моему, вы здесь выложили html код не к этому js коду. И при чем тут this.val == 2 ?

Comment: @Leonid вы правы... А как мне можно отключить больше значений?

Comment: @Incover Как показано в ответе.

Comment: @Leonid не выкладывал весь html. Если product меняется то пропадают блоки и отключаются опции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Селектор работает:

```js
$(".js_country option").removeAttr("disabled");

$(".js_country option[value='6']").text("AUSTRALIA").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$("option[value='7']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row js_country">
  <label for="country">Страна происхождения</label>
  <select class="service_custom_select" id="country" name="fuel" aria-invalid="false">
    <option name="country_id" value="1" disabled>Страна 1</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="2">Страна 2</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="3">Страна 3</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="4">Страна 4</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="5">Страна 5</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="6">Страна не отключена</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="7">Страна отключена </option>
    <option name="country_id" value="8">Страна 8</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Буду разбираться. А убрать disable я так понимаю $(".js_country option").removeAttr("disabled");

Comment: @Incover da *(4 символа нужно...)*

Answer (score 2):

**Можно же тоже самое на нормальном языке: ))**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.js_country option').forEach(opt => opt.disabled = false);

document.querySelector(".js_country option[value='6']").disabled = true;

document.querySelector("option[value='7']").disabled = true;
```

```html
<div class="row js_country">
  <label for="country">Страна происхождения</label>
  <select class="service_custom_select" id="country" name="fuel" aria-invalid="false">
    <option name="country_id" value="1" disabled>Страна 1</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="2">Страна 2</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="3">Страна 3</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="4">Страна 4</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="5">Страна 5</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="6">Страна не отключена</option>
    <option name="country_id" value="7">Страна отключена </option>
    <option name="country_id" value="8">Страна 8</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Australia text не стал добавлять. Не понял зачем он, без этого селектор не работает?